# Is there a .NET Standard equivalent for Trace.CorrelationManager?

Tags: nlog, .net-core

In my .NET Framework 4.6.1 Web API applications, I'm using the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class' `CorrelationManager` property, along with NLog, to group log messages per request. Unfortunately, it seems like the `CorrelationManager` property no longer exists on `System.Diagnostics.Trace`. I have two questions:

1. Is there a replacement concept somewhere in .NET Standard?
2. Does NLog natively support that replacement?

Comment: You could easily add it to NLog with some c# code: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending%20NLog#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` is what I am looking for. NLog does not currently support this.

Answer (score 4):

It's already supported from version 4.3.1 of NLog.Web. Use variable `${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}`.

You can use also custom one with custom logic, for example:

```
app.Use(next => {
                return async context => {
                    context.TraceIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    await next(context);
                };
            });
```